# Is the phrase "in despite of" instead of "in spite of" incorrect?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Is the usage of the phrase "in despite of" instead of "in spite of" in the following passage from Charles Dickens' Little Dorrit, chapter 15 incorrect or is it a Dickensian peculiarity?

> Then the bell rang once more, and then once more, and then kept on ringing; in despite of which importunate summons, Affery still sat behind her apron, recovering her breath.

Answer (score 1):

*in despite of* occurs more often in old texts, including Shakespeare.

Here is an ngram graph comparing it to simple *despite*:
[Google Ngram in despite of, despite](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20despite%20of%2Cdespite&year_start=1500&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3)

Here is another, comparing it to *in spite of*:
[Google Ngram in despite of, in spite of](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20despite%20of%2Cin%20spite%20of&year_start=1500&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20despite%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20spite%20of%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: I'm not sure how accurate Google NGram is in very old texts (e.g. pre-1600), both due to OCR errors and incorrect dates (a lot of results for early dates seem to be later reprints or translations). But despite that, a Google Books search definitely shows some examples of "in despite of" from very old texts.